# Twilio XML response to SMS

Tags: c#, xml, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to complete a sample SMS app with Twilio where I send a SMS message to my Twilio number and the Twilio service sends me back a reply. I know the Twilio service is reaching my API because I can see the incoming request from Twilio reaching my API and I can see the response of my API, but I think somethng is wrong, as I never get an SMS response back.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("EchoTest")]
public IHttpActionResult EchoTest()
{
    string response = "<Response><Sms>Thanks for the message</Sms></Response>";
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter()));
}
```

I am returning the `ResponseMessage` so I can be consistent in returning an `IHttpActionResult`. I have also tried returning just `HttpResponseMessage` as seen below with the same results.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("EchoTest")]
public HttpResponseMessage EchoTest()
{
    string response = "<Response><Sms>Thanks for the message</Sms></Response>";
    Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
}
```

This is what my API is sending back ...

```
<string
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;Response&gt;&lt;Sms&gt;Thanks for the message&lt;/Sms&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;
</string>
```

Am I messing up the XML response? What I am looking to send back to Twilio is this ...

```
<Response><Sms>Thanks for the message</Sms></Response>
```

Answer (score 3):

See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969056(v=vs.118).aspx
Try this

```
XElement response = XElement.Parse("<Response><Sms>Thanks for the message</Sms></Response>");
    Request.CreateResponse<XElement>(request, HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```

Comment: Thanks! The XElement code worked. Although I did have to send it back using `return Request.CreateResponse<XElement>(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());`